# Showing $|x_n -x|$ converges to x

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I'm given a generic sequence $x_n$, and I know that $\lim_{n ->\infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|} < 1$ and exists. I'm trying to show that $x_n$ converges to $x$.

I tried a bunch of approaches, but the farthest I got was a proof by contradiction where I try show that $\lim_{n->\infty} |x_n-x|$ cannot be greater than 0, but instead must equal 0, resulting in $x_n$ converging to $x$.

Can I get some assistance?

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It is equivalent to show tha $|x_n-x|\to 0$. Now, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|} $ exists and is $<1$, there exists $k<1$ and $N_0$ such that
$$\frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|}\le k\quad\forall n \ge N_0.$$

Deduce that, for all $n\ge N_0$, one has $\;|x_n-x|\le k^{n-N_0}\,|x_{N_0}-x|$ (use induction on $n$) and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

If we define $a_n=|x_n-x|$, then proving that $x_n$ converges to $x$ is equivalent to proving that $a_n$ converges to $0$.

This is clear since

1. $x_n$ converges to $x$ if and only if

   > For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, $$|x_n-x|<\epsilon$$
2. $a_n$ converges to $0$ if and only if

   > For each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N>0$ such that for $n>N$, $$|a_n-0|<\epsilon$$

The two conditions are clearly identical, since $|a_n-0|=|a_n|=||x_n-x||=|x_n-x|$.

---

To prove that $a_n$ converges to $0$, let's first see what we know about $a_n$. We know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$$

Here's what I would advise you to do next:

1. Prove that there exists some $c<1$ such that for a large enough $N$, it is true that if $n>N$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < c$
2. Then, use the fact that that same inequality translates to $a_{n+1}<c\cdot a_n$ (again, for $n>N$).
3. From that, you can see that $a_{n+1}<c\cdot a_n<c\cdot(c\cdot a_{n-1})<c\cdot(c\cdot(c\cdot a_{n-2}))<\cdots$ if $n$ is large enough.
4. Can you continue from here?